# Angular 2 - Cancel Service Call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a menu with category tabs and the following function on click.

```
this._customerservice.GetCustomersByFilter(this.FilterOptions) //Get Customers by Page Number and CategoryId
            .subscribe(res => {

                if (this.customersArray.paginatedCustomers.length != 0) {
                    res.paginatedCustomers.forEach(element => {
                        this.customersArray.paginatedCustomers.push(element);
                    });
                }

                else
                    this.customersArray = res;

               if (infiniteScroll != null)
                infiniteScroll.complete();
                this.customersView = this.customersArray;
            }
```

Once he clicks on a category and the service call is still loading, if he clicks on the 2nd category, I want to stop this function of returning a result because it is producing wrong output for the wrong category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `subscribe` returns a **Subscription**. You can cancel the subscription by calling the `unsubscribe` method. Example:

```
this.customerSubscription = this._customerservice.GetCustomersByFilter(...).subscribe(...);

// cancel the subscription
this.customerSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: ok so when I put the unsubscribe above , it should unsubscribe all the previous requests? I will try now

Comment: I got unsubscribe is not a function

Comment: @MissakBoyajian Maybe your rxjs version is different. Try `dispose()` instead of `unsubscribe()`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html).  It's often used in conjunction with Debounce.

Also [RangeIo](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/search_with_switchmap.html) has a nice article.

Comment: Why did I get a -1? I mean your category change is effectively calling for a request you want to override. This does the same. Quote: switchMap will automatically unsubscribe from any previous observable when a new event comes down the stream.

Comment: I did not -1. I am now checking it. It looks a bit complicated but I keep you posted if it worked